# What is the buzzing noise I hear for about 30 seconds before my furnace blower starts?

Tags: hvac

There's a buzzing sound for about 30 seconds prior to the blower starting. Everything seems to be working normally, but I don't recall hearing this sound before.

Here's a video, the blower starts normally at about 20 seconds.

[Buzzing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVsgR0WAkKw)

Comment: Could be the ignitor spark, but it seems too loud for that.

Answer (score 3):

A possibility is that this sound is a noisy flue inducer motor rather than the main blower motor. This is just suggestion for you to investigate. If the sound starts right after the thermostat calls for heat and before the burner turns on, then I think this is it. The main blower does not get called until a while after the main burner comes on and heats up the heat exchanger.

Maybe the flue inducer fan motor has its bearings worn, or maybe service of the inducer is required. Apparently this inducer makes a draft through the flue until the main burner turns on. It may be that then the inducer motor is depowered when the burner comes on. If so, the heated combustion gases in the flue are sufficient to pull air through. Or it may be that the inducer motor stays on but the hot exhaust gases put a smaller load on the fan and so the bearings are quieter.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4Lzxk6-of0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sNUAsIFW3g

Google this e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYn6VWV0HNY

Answer (score 1):

Buzz, could be a failing motor, worn or unlubricated bearings, or a failing run capacitor. The motor is trying to turn, or start, and it's not getting the juice it needs, or it's dirty and needs lubricated.

Comment: From the Buzz video I cannot tell whether it is the main blower which is "trying to start" but cannot or it is the inducer motor. I am not sure all furnaces have inducers so obviously if yours doesn't, then it is the main blower. Maybe just the start/run capacitor is bad.